How to Show a Hidden Label When Hovering Over a Button?
We all know you can change the colour of a button when you hover over it in CSS alone.
But, what would I do to make a label within it show up when I hover over it?
Effectively, my button just has an icon/image in it when it is in normal mode. But, when the user hovers over the button it will show a text label as well.
I realise you can put a title into the button with gives a text description of what the button does, but can you put a label into a button when you hover over it?
Is that a good idea, or should I just stick to using title?
Ie, here is my button in normal state:
<button>
    <img src="./images/iconok.png" alt="Submit" />
    <label style="display: none">&nbsp;Submit</label>
</button>

and in my hovered state
<button>
    <img src="./images/iconok.png" alt="Submit" />
    <label style="display: inline-block">&nbsp;Submit</label>
</button>

How do I implement this?
Note: When the button is not being hovered over, I do not want any space being allocated to the label at all, as if it was not even there.
EDIT: I have made a mistake in my original question that affected the answer. I had display: block; on my label, which caused the label to appear below the image, but should have been display: inline-block; to make it appear at the side.

A label does not belong into button, that is invalid HTML.

Its working. However, should it be a span to be valid HTML? If not, what do you use to section off a bit of text so you can hide and show it?

Yeah, span should do fine here.

Your question is little bit confusing, but is this what you wanted?:
HTML:
<button>
    <img src="./images/iconok.png" alt="Submit" />
    <label class="btn-label">&nbsp;Submit</label>
</button>

CSS:
.btn-label {
  display: none;
}

button:hover .btn-label {
  display: inline-block;
}


This is the one I like the most due to its simplicity. I made an error in my question, which has resulted in an effect in your code I was not desiring. I have corrected my question. Could you please edit your answer (ie put display: inline-block; on the hover label section.

One question. Is there any way I can just do the button:hover on only the labels with btn-label class? Some of my buttons have other labels which I want unaffected.

@Rewind Yes, updated the CSS, please check. Now only the labels with btn-label class will be hidden and will be shown on hower.


Use visibility: hidden to prevent the label from taking up any
space when hidden.
And visibility: visible with :hover pseudo-selector to display it on hover of button inside button.

